# How do you include .scss file to a component in angular2?

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

Hi I have a styling done in scss for a component and I want to apply that. 
I have already installed: `npm install node-sass sass-loader raw-loader --save-dev`

and in my component, I have:

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'product-detail',
  templateUrl: 'app/products/product-detail.component.html',
  styles: ['app/products/product-detail.component.scss']
})
```

in my webpack.commons.configs.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/main.tsx'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    loaders: {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
}
};
```

Regular css styling gets applied correctly but scss is not working. 
I tried changing   `styles: [require('app/products/product-detail.component.scss').toString()]` in @component, but it changes my scss file to scss.js file.

I have googled everywhere, but can't seem to find a working solution.
Anyone has any idea?

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components

Comment: Yea, I followed the instructions from there, and scss file still doesn't get applied. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **use `styleUrls`** and **not `styles`** to include your file. Code will look something like below

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'product-detail',
  templateUrl: 'app/products/product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/products/product-detail.component.scss']
})
```