# How to import .scss file to app.js parent file as a global?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

I'm starting an Angular project and have been following these steps to import the scss files - https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components

- So looking at src/scss my `style.scss` is present
- `webpack.common.js` has a sass loader module defined - `sassLoader: {
  includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/scss')],
  sourceMap: true
  },`

I've also looked at a similar question on SO posted here which doesn't explain how to import the style globally:

[How do you include .scss file to a component in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704984/how-do-you-include-scss-file-to-a-component-in-angular2)
But in comparison with the example linked above my app.js file is configured like so:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import Components from './components/components';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {
  CheapFlightService,
  AirportsService
} from './services';



angular.module('myApp', [
  uiRouter,
  Components
])
.component('homePage', HomeComponent)
.service('AiportsService', AirportsService)
.service('CheapFlightService', CheapFlightService)
.config(($stateProvider) => {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '',
      template: '<home-page></home-page>'
    });
});
```

**Question:**

How can you import .scss file to app.js parent file as a global?

style.scss file:

```
//----------------------------------*\
// SCSS MIXINS
//----------------------------------*/

@import 'mixins/_position.scss';
@import 'mixins/_selection.scss';
@import 'mixins/_vendor.scss';
@import 'mixins/_other-mixins.scss';

//----------------------------------*\
// CONFIG MODULES
//----------------------------------*/

// Config modules
@import 'modules/_vars.scss';
@import 'modules/_clearfix.scss';
@import 'modules/_defaults.scss';

//----------------------------------*\
// PARTIALS
//----------------------------------*/

@import 'partials/_header.scss';
@import 'partials/_nav.scss';
@import 'partials/_sidebar.scss';
@import 'partials/_main.scss';
@import 'partials/_footer.scss';

//----------------------------------*\
// OBJECTS & MODULES
//----------------------------------*/

@import 'modules/_buttons.scss';
@import 'modules/_inputs.scss';
@import 'modules/_lists.scss';
@import 'modules/_typography.scss';
@import 'modules/_misc.scss';
@import 'modules/_app.scss';

// Enhancement modules
@import 'modules/_breakpoints.scss';
@import 'modules/_print.scss';
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack-vendor-chunk-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['ng-annotate','babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
      // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'},
      // helps to load bootstrap's css.
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.woff2$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&minetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&minetype=image/svg+xml' }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    // add alias for application code directory
    // alias: {
    //   '~': path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src')
    // },
  },

  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/scss')],
    sourceMap: true
  },

  postcss: function() {
    return [autoprefixer];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, sassLoader and postcss are not valid webpack config attributes https://webpack.js.org/configuration

The way you would typically go about it is to add the .scss file to your entry

```
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    styles: './pathtoyourstyles/style.scss'
  },
```

and then add the appropriate loaders.

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
  }
]
```

Comment: Makes sense does that setup make the scss global? For example accessible in the app.js or any of my other component files?

Comment: it makes the styles available to any html file included in the webpack bundle.  You can also export the scss file to its own file using the webpack extract text plugin, but that is a bit more of an advanced webpack configuration, and you will want to be on the latest version of webpack for that.